# Eclipse Gradle adding a classpath entry

Tags: java, eclipse, gradle, buildship

I'm adding a classpath entry to the .classpath file in Eclipse to avoid having to add it manually each time I run the .eclipse task while I add a number of dependencies. I need some resources on the path to run locally.

this works,

```
eclipse.classpath.file {
   withXml { 
     def node = it.asNode()
     node.appendNode('classpathentry', 
                [kind: 'lib', path: '/some/path'])
           }
}
```

this doesn't,

```
eclipse.classpath.file {
   whenMerged { classpath ->
      classpath.entries.add { entry -> kind: 'lib', path: '/some/path' }
              }
}
```

The error I get is,

startup failed: build.gradle': 75: unexpected token: lib @ line 75, column 48.
.entries.add { entry -> kind: 'lib', pat
                              ^

For future reference, what is wrong with the second example?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The equivalent should be something like:

```
eclipse.classpath.file {
  whenMerged { classpath ->
    def lib = new org.gradle.plugins.ide.eclipse.model.Library(fileReference(file('path/to/my/jar')))
    lib.exported = true
    classpath.entries << lib
  }
}
```

See Gradle docs for [Library](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/plugins/ide/eclipse/model/Library.html) and its interface [ClasspathEntry](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/plugins/ide/eclipse/model/ClasspathEntry.html).